# OSX - Rename multiple files with .5 increment

Tags: macos, batch-rename

i need to rename multiple files but with .5 increment. Any ideias?

**EX:**

```
"0001.jpg" - "A-BCD-30.jpg"
"0002.jpg" - "A-BCD-30.5.jpg"
"0003.jpg" - "A-BCD-31.jpg"
"0004.jpg" - "A-BCD-31.5.jpg"
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="A-BCD-"
value=30
odd=false

for file in `ls -1 | sort`; do
    if [ "$odd" == "true" ]; then
          odd=false
          echo ${prefix}${value}.5.jpg
          # cp $file ${prefix}${value}.5.jpg
          let value=$value+1
        else
          odd=true
          echo ${prefix}${value}.jpg
          # cp $file ${prefix}${value}.5.jpg
        fi

done
```